# Groovy compiler not complaining for not catching a checked exception

Tags: groovy

I am using the following function in a groovy script:

```
private static List<List<String>> getCheckerFrameworkErrors(final String profile) {
    // ----- Non relevant section starts
    final List<String> checkerFrameworkLines = new ArrayList<>()
    final String command = "mvn -e --no-transfer-progress clean compile -P${profile}"
    final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(getOsSpecificCmd(command).split(' '))
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true)
    final Process process = processBuilder.start()
    // ----- Non relevant section ends

    // ----- Relevant section starts
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
    String lineFromReader = reader.readLine()
    while (lineFromReader != null) {
        println(lineFromReader)
        checkerFrameworkLines.add(lineFromReader)
        lineFromReader = reader.readLine()
    }
    process.waitFor()
    reader.close()
    // ----- Relevant section ends
}
```

This method does not explicitly throw an exception and the signature of `readLine()` function is:

```
public String readLine() throws IOException
```

The signature of `waitFor()` is:

```
public abstract int waitFor() throws InterruptedException
```

which throws `InterruptedException` which is also another checked exception, still not error is thrown by the compiler.

groovy version is `4.0.3`

According to my current knowledge, `IOException` is a checked exception and must be handled by a `try-catch` block or by explicitly adding `throws` to the method, but this script executes successfully without any error, what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after some research, found the answer to the question:

From Groovy docs:

> Groovy automatically allows you to treat checked exceptions like unchecked exceptions. This means that you don’t need to declare any checked exceptions that a method may throw

Source: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_exception_declaration

Comment: On the one hand, it's handy, but on the other hand, it forces you always to remember about try-catches and place them. So, I prefer a Rust-like error handling with `Either<Error, Success>`.